# awk is printing 2 double output

Tags: wordpress, awk

I'm trying to figure out when running;

```
awk -F\' '/wp_version/ { print "WP Version:\033[1;32m" $2 "\033[0m" }' wp-includes/version.php
```

It outputs

```
WP Version:
WP Version:4.2.2
```

When running

```
awk -F\' '/DB_NAME/ { print "Database Name:\033[1;31m" $4 "\033[0m" }' wp-config.php
```

Outputs:

```
Database Name:db_name
```

Not seeing why the first command prints double.

Comment: there are multiple lines matching `/wp_version/`

Comment: @mescalinum is probably right but did you try removing the escape sequences from your script? Did you notice one uses `32m` while the other `31m` in the first escape sequence? Have you checked for control chars in your first input file (use `cat -v` to see them)?

Comment: Yeah it was multiple lines matching.  It's always the little things.
There is a commented out line. 
Thank you